# How to extract an html text from an xml? (Parser Rapture XML, language Objective C)

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xml

It is possible with an xml parser to extract an html text?

Explaining in detail:
I have this simple xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<eventi>
<evento><id_evento>4553</id_evento><descrizione>Lorem Ipsum<a href='http://www.yea.it/yea.asp' target='_blank'><span class='U'>Vai alla pagina di gioco</span></a></descrizione></evento>
</eventi>
```

and i'm parsing it with rapture XML, while developing an app for IOS. When i do

```
rootXML = [RXMLElement elementFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", indXMLdettaglioEvento, idElemento]]];
[rootXML iterateWithRootXPath:@"//evento" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement *datiXML) {
      NSLog(@"%@",[datiXML child:@"descrizione"].text);;
]}
```

The nslog of [datiXML child:@"descrizione"].text returns the text without the html tags. It is possible to make it return the entire html?

Comment: please NSLog like : `NSLog(@"%@",[datiXML child:@"descrizione"]);`

Comment: did it, it return the text without html

Comment: HTML is not a subset of XML, hence you will not be able to reliably parse HTML using any XML parser. xHTML however is a subset and should, if used properly, be parseable using an XML parser (e.g. RaptureXML).

Comment: so there's no hope to parse the html text complete of its tags?

Comment: @ElisabettaFalivene my comment was more of a general nature and to me it seems that your specific example is wellformed XML, hence should be parseable.

Comment: Mmm, i don't understand what are you suggesting to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [datiXML child:@"descrizione"]
```

returns a parsed XML item which has a text of Lorem Ipsum, but it also has children itself!  The first child, I think you find, is  going to be an XML item for your link anchor:

```
 [[dataiXML child::@"descrizione"] child: @"a"]  => XML item for link
 [[[dataiXML child::@"descrizione"] child: @"a"] child: @"span"] => XML item for span
```

So you'll need to traverse the whole tree to parse your xHTML -- but I think you'll find it's all there.

As previous commenters have said, lots of valid HTML pages are not valid XML. And lots of HTML pages that "work" aren't valid!  So this wouldn't be a good strategy for writing a Web browser. But that's not what we're doing here; if the service you're talking to delivers XML, it makes perfect sense to use an XML parser to parse it!

Comment: Interesting! what do you mean by "trasverse" the whole tree"? I keep not understanding. You mean i need to search inside every child "descrizione" if there's an "a", a "span", a "img" and so on? Seem complicated...

Comment: Take another look at the Rapture XML documentation. It has methods for retrieving an array of all the child elements that match a query, or for passing each of them to a block.  You won't know WHICH elements you'll be getting in the HTML so you'll  pass an XPath wildcard like `descrizione/*` to get an array of all the children of descrizione

Answer (score 0):

You can use some open source libraries like TinyXML, TouchXML etc for parsing XML documents.

Otherwise you can write your own parser using NSXMLParser.

Hope this Helps !!!

Comment: I developed a very complicate app, it's not the right time to change parser, unfortunately ^^'

Comment: Why would RaptureXML not do? From my experience, it is a great parser.